# How to get "byte" size of gzipped string?

Tags: php, compression, gzip

For example, if I have:

```
$string = 'hello world';
$byteSize = strlen($string);
```

$byteSize would show the actual byte size of the string because the string is ASCII characters. But if I gzencode this:

```
$string = 'hello world';
$string = gzencode($string);
$byteSize = strlen($string);
```

Is $byteSize still the true size of the string in bytes?

**NOTE**
I'm using this to compare the size of a downloaded URL in the case of it being compressed and not compressed. I know how to check the size if it is compressed, but I want to know the potential size if it's not compressed. So I compress the 'body' of the url and then want to check the size, so I can tell the user the estimated size he could be downloading, had gzip been enabled.

Comment: wouldent you have to uncompress it first to get the size?, if im reading your question correctly

Comment: `$byteSize` is the length of the encoded string, which is not the same as the original string, so it is different. https://3v4l.org/Njf5O